# SQLite validation in Qt

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

Problem: validating incoming(to program) sqlite database. Under "validate" i mean check that database have specific tables, table names, column(name, type, foreign and primary keys).

Qt provide some ways how to do it but i still cant find how to check foreign keys in table, column types.

Have someone elegant solution of this problem? Examples required too=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do it manually. Here's a simple (untested) example for checking for required tables.

```
bool hasRequiredTables()
{
    QStringList reqTables;
    QStringList tables;

    reqTables<< "table1" << "table2" << "table3" << "etc";

    QString sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master"
                  " WHERE type = 'table'"
                  " AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite%';";

    QSqlQuery query ( sql, QSqlDatabase::database () );

    if ( !query.isValid() ){
       return false;
    }

    while ( query.next() )
       tables.append ( query.value ( 0 ).toString() );


    foreach ( QString t, reqTables ){
        if ( !tables.contains ( t, Qt::CaseInsensitive ) ){
           //qDebug() << "non-existent table: " << t;
           return false;
        }
    }

    // OK
    return true;
}
```

Other checks should be as trivial as this one once you're familiar enough with the information available in the `sqlite_master` table.

Comment: oh damn i really forgot about master table. thanks. is this one way to do this?

Comment: @Torv I did it once for a project. This was my approach and it worked pretty well. For the indexes maybe you can use `QSqlIndex QSqlTableModel::primaryKey () const` if you're willing to use a "heavy" class like `QSqlTableModel` instead of plain SQL queries.

Comment: whoops.. sorry, I meant to say primary keys, not indexes. For the indexes it's perfectly possible to do it by querying the `sqlite_master` as in the example above.